# How to compute log likelihood for impossible events?

Tags: infinity, ratio, log-likelihood

I am defining a set $\mathbf{Z} = [p,q,r,s]$ such that $Pr(p)+Pr(q)+Pr(r)+Pr(s)=1$.

Likelihoods are defined as follows

\begin{align}
 \lambda_p&=\log \frac{Pr(x=p)}{Pr(x=s)}, \hspace{2mm} \lambda_q=\log \frac{Pr(x=q)}{Pr(x=s)}\\[15pt]
 \lambda_r&=\log \frac{Pr(x=r)}{Pr(x=s)}, \hspace{2mm} \lambda_s=\log \frac{Pr(x=s)}{Pr(x=s)}=0
\end{align}

If $Pr(p)=1$ then $Pr(q)=Pr(r)=Pr(s)=0$. In this case

\begin{align}
 \lambda_p&=\log \frac{Pr(x=p)}{Pr(x=s)}=\infty
\end{align}

But I don't understand what values will $\lambda_q,\lambda_r,\lambda_s$ take.

Comment: That definition of likelihood seems confusing, given the definition on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of log-likelihood is not standard.
It is usually defined as the log of the probability of a given event given the distribution.

\begin{align}
 \lambda_p&=\log Pr(x=p), \hspace{2mm} \lambda_q=\log Pr(x=q) \dots
\end{align}

it is always negative and is set to $-\infty$ when the event is impossible.

If you need to keep the quantities that you have defined, you have, actually, differences between log-likelihoods and they are not well defined for 2 likelihoods equal to $-\infty$

(I would have post that as a comment but do not have enough reputation for that)